# SQL Query to display unique records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 columns email,fname,lname I want to Query to display unique records taking into account it should pick only one records if more than one record exists with same email,same fname and same lname.What should be the Query like?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT email, fname, lname FROM tbl`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql limiting for unique records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754648/sql-limiting-for-unique-records)

Comment: Not that this is a very difficult question, but remember to always post some sample data.

Comment: Do you need any columns other than email/fname/lname in the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select email, lname, fname
  from table1
  group by email, lname, fname
  having count(*) > 1  --only records with duplicates, 
                       --group by will return only one occurance
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I need to get all unique records not the records with duplicates alone.

Comment: ok.. In that case just the distinct of those columns should work.